# Firebase Notifications using FCM to Topics

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi i am trying to send notifications to all the devices that subscribe to a particular topic using Swift. I want to send the push manually by code not by Firebase console. Here is the code i have written.

```
public static func sendPush(){
    if let url = URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"){
        var urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.addValue("key = AIzaSyBaaaaaaaaaaaa-NbAUq3iMYmw", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let dic: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
            "to" : "/topics/News",
            "priority" : "high",
            "notification" :[
                "body" : "This is a notification",
                "title" : "FCM Notification"
            ]

        ]


        do{
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted)
            urlRequest.httpBody = data
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            print("JSON Object Serialized")
        }
        catch{

        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in
            print("Inside Task")
            if error != nil{
                print("Push \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
            if response != nil {
                print("Data : \(response)")
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

When i execute the above function by calling it i get status code 200. That means okay, request was successful. But my devices who subscribe to this Topic do not receive notification. 
I do subscribe for notifications too but nothing happens.
When i try to send notifications using Firebase console to individual devices, they receive notifications but not via the code.
I was reading this documentation [Tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-multiple)

This is what it prints in the console after this request completes

```
Data : Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170225560> { URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 54;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Fri, 12 May 2017 21:14:52 GMT";
Expires = "Fri, 12 May 2017 21:14:52 GMT";
Server = GSE;
"alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"37,36,35\"";
"x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
"x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
} })
```

Please help me through this and guid me what i am doing wrong and how should i achieve success? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this is the case, but AFAIK, the topic name is case-sensitive. In your code, you're sending a message to the `News` topic. But in the documentation you referred to, you're subscribing to the `news` topic. Have you tried matching both?

Comment: No i am using uppercase for both subscribing and pushing notifications

Comment: Oh really sorry guys, it is working now. I read somewhere that it takes upto 24 hours to appear in the console. Now i can see the topic in the console and i can send it too. The notifications are sent.